# I cannot locate my Mardek 2 save file

Tags: mardek-2

I was playing Mardek on kongregate.com using Google chrome, and decided to move to a different site.  So I went to check my flash app data folder and the chat.kongregate doesn't have my save information? I tried to clear out the folder and see if it was still there, and my save still worked on the site, but I have no idea where it is! I even cleared the entire app data folder looking for it and it still worked!

Comment: Don't flash games use cookies unless allowed to store local data? Perhaps Mardek, being an old game now, still uses a cookie-based save system.